# Broadleaf not building or starting with Java > 8: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, broadleaf-commerce

I was following the [Broadleaf Getting Started](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started/running-locally) tutorial and got several odd errors (NullPointer and Bean Not Found exceptions).

TL;DR: Broadleaf 6.0.x works with Java 8-10 (build, run). When importing maven dependencies, they also need to be imported with a target to JDK 8 (hint: multi release jar). Also it works only on HotSpot VM (not OpenJ9).

Official statement (from Broadleaf Gitter):

> The supported version of Java is closely tied to the version of
>   Spring. Broadleaf version 6.0.x is using Spring Framework
>   5.0.8.RELEASE which supports JDK 8-10 (we continue to recommend Java 8). JDK 11 is not supported until Spring Framework 5.1 which we will
>   be upgrading in our 6.1.0-GA release. I don't have a release date for
>   6.1.0-GA yet but will be before year end.

Reproduce:

```
git clone 
mvn clean install
cd site
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Versions: tags/broadleaf-6.0.6-GA and develop-6.0.x.

```
2019-10-15 12:12:08.502 WARN 1041 --- [ main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
```

System setup (inside Docker):

```
openjdk 12.0.1 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 12.0.1+12)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM AdoptOpenJDK (build openj9-0.14.1, JRE 12 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20190418_66 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9 - 412258978
OMR - 4a4278e6
JCL - 9fad1c64af based on jdk-12.0.1+12)
```

System setup (on MacOS):

```
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11, mixed mode)
Apache Maven 3.6.2
```

Full stack trace:

```
    ...]
2019-10-15 12:12:05.847  INFO 1041 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2019-10-15 12:12:05.850  INFO 1041 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-10-15 12:12:05.891  INFO 1041 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2019-10-15 12:12:07.509  INFO 1041 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.broadleafcommerce.common.dialect.DemoHSQLDialect
2019-10-15 12:12:07.607  INFO 1041 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.e.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl    : Envers integration enabled? : true
2019-10-15 12:12:08.416 ERROR 1041 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'siteSecurityConfig': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blUserDetailsService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blCustomerService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blCustomerDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blEntityManagerFactorySecureInfo' defined in class path resource [bl-framework-applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: blSecurePU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
2019-10-15 12:12:08.447  INFO 1041 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-10-15 12:12:08.471  WARN 1041 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HSQLDB Timer @6c7be24e] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:221)
 org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer$TaskQueue.park(Unknown Source)
 org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer.nextTask(Unknown Source)
 org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer$TaskRunner.run(Unknown Source)
 java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)

...

 java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
2019-10-15 12:12:08.502  WARN 1041 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2019-10-15 12:12:08.503  INFO 1041 --- [           main] o.s.jmx.export.MBeanExporter             : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2019-10-15 12:12:08.516  INFO 1041 --- [           main] b.c.e.c.e.MergeEhCacheManagerFactoryBean : Shutting down EhCache CacheManager
2019-10-15 12:12:08.529  INFO 1041 --- [           main] o.b.c.c.e.AbstractHydratedCacheManager   : Disposing of all hydrated cache members
2019-10-15 12:12:08.533  INFO 1041 --- [           main] o.b.c.c.e.AbstractHydratedCacheManager   : Disposing of all hydrated cache members
2019-10-15 12:12:08.539  INFO 1041 --- [           main] o.b.c.c.e.AbstractHydratedCacheManager   : Disposing of all hydrated cache members
2019-10-15 12:12:08.546  INFO 1041 --- [           main] o.b.c.c.e.AbstractHydratedCacheManager   : Disposing of all hydrated cache members
2019-10-15 12:12:08.602  INFO 1041 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-15 12:12:08.623 ERROR 1041 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.community.SiteApplication.main(SiteApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'siteSecurityConfig': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blUserDetailsService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blCustomerService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blCustomerDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blEntityManagerFactorySecureInfo' defined in class path resource [bl-framework-applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: blSecurePU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

...

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: blSecurePU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 95 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 103 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 113 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 119 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.329 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-15T12:12:08Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project boot-community-demo-site: Could not exec java: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Seems like javaassist lib needs to be of some updated version. It probably has a static version defined in BOM in your case, and that version doesn't support changes in Java9, which an updated version might have. Alternatively, you might be missing some runtime `--add-opens` flags, which would be discussed in upgrade checklist for relevant libs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this seems to really be a problem with the Java JRE Version.

I found only Java 8 is supported and you must ensure that:
- maven builds the artefacts with Java 8
- maven imports and configures the correct dependencies (hint: multi release jar)
- java 8 is used to run the application

Also, you must ensure that you are running on the HotSpot VM. I got errors trying to run it on OpenJ9.

Places to check:

- `java -version` ~1.8.x
- [Intellij] `Preferences/Settings -> Build -> Maven -> Importing and Runner` JDK, JRE ~1.8.x
- [Intellij] `Project Settings -> Project -> Project SDK` JDK, JRE ~1.8.x

You could use a tool like SDKMAN to flexibly change the JDKs and experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency to you site/pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Any specific reason why it's not the latest 3.26?

Comment: give it a try, why not

Comment: We've got some other blockers, but I'll report back